# unable to find the data type for List of String or Array of String in Oracle DB

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, liquibase

I am using liquibase changeset to insert the string array or list of multiple string but issue is I am not able to find which data types to use, even I have checked the site ->
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A58617_01/server.804/a58241/ch5.htm

Here is my changeset which I am using

```
    <changeSet id="1639718925269-1" author="bharatsuthar">
        <addColumn tableName="users">
            <column name="permissions" type="varchar(30)[]"/>
        </addColumn>
    </changeSet>

    <changeSet id="1639718925270-1" author="sahilgoel">
        <insert tableName="users">
            <column name="user_id" value="hgw-rdk@telekom-digital.com"/>
            <column name="created_at" valueComputed="((SYSDATE - date '1970-01-01')*24*60*60*1000)"/>
            <column name="modified_at" valueComputed="((SYSDATE - date '1970-01-01')*24*60*60*1000)"/>
            <column name="permissions" value="('DOWNLOAD_PHASE_II_FILE','DOWNLOAD_PHASE_III_FILE','DOWNLOAD_MERGED_FILE','DOWNLOAD_ERROR_FILE')"/>
        </insert>
    </changeSet>
```

problem is when i see the DDL of varchar(30)[] then I found that it is simple varchar only instead of array of varchar hence I am facing issue of storing strings into the array and also I could not find the array of string type in data type of oracle db..now what should I do ?

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle, if you want to store an array of string then you would use either a nested table or a `VARRAY` collection data type.

There are built-in `VARRAY` data types such as `SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST` or you can define your own nested table collection using:

```sql
CREATE TYPE string_list IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(30);
```

And then use:

```sql
ALTER TABLE users ADD (permissions string_list)
  NESTED TABLE permissions STORE AS users_permissions;
```

You will need to look up the Liquibase documentation to see if it supports nested tables and collection data types.

---

Alternatively, just create a second table with the columns `user_id` and `permission`.

Comment: it shows invalid data type ```Caused by: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: ORA-00902: invalid datatype
 [Failed SQL: (902) ALTER TABLE SYSTEM.users ADD permissions VARRAY]```

Comment: @EVExperience `VARRAY` is not an instance of a data type, it is a category of data types. If you want to use a `VARRAY` then use `SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST` or create your own instance of a user-defined `VARRAY` data type using `CREATE TYPE string_varray IS VARRAY(10) OF VARCHAR2(30);` (to store at most 10 strings of up to 30 characters in length each) and use that.

Comment: I used ```SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST```, I was able to insert the column ```permissions``` but not able to insert values of permissions using this liquibase changeset ```<column name="permissions" value="DOWNLOAD_PHASE_II_FILE,DOWNLOAD_PHASE_III_FILE,DOWNLOAD_MERGED_FILE,DOWNLOAD_ERROR_FILE"/>``` , got this issue -> ```Caused by: oracle.jdbc.OracleDatabaseException: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST got CHAR``` can you please help me ? basically I don't know correct syntax, it looks like so

Comment: @EVExperience You need to ask a Liquibase expert or consult the documentation. I can only tell you how to do what you want in Oracle and not in Liquibase. Personally, I would not use an array and would use a second table.

Comment: In Oracle you would insert `SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST('DOWNLOAD_PHASE_II_FILE','DOWNLOAD_PHASE_III_FILE','DOWNLOAD_MERGED_FILE','DOWNLOAD_ERROR_FILE')` but, as previously said, you need to consult the Liquibase documentation for how to do it in Liquibase.